# python gdata, extracting numbers from output

Tags: python, gdata

I'm still new to Python and I've been working with a script to get system info from my Raspberry Pi, like cpu temp and such and import it to a google doc spreadsheet. My goal is to extract the numbers from the output, which is in the form `temp=54.1'C`. I need the numbers alone to be able to graph the data over time...

I'm using:

```
import gdata.spreadsheet.service
import os
import subprocess
import re

email = 'myemail@gmail.com'
password = 'mypassword'

spreadsheet_key = 'sjdaf;ljaslfjasljdgasjdflasdjfgkjvja'
worksheet_id = '1'

def temp():
   command = "/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp"
   proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
   output = proc.stdout.read()
   return output

def main():
   spr_client = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()
   spr_client.email = email
   spr_client.password = password
   spr_client.ProgrammaticLogin()

   dict = {}
   dict['temp'] = temp()

   entry = spr_client.InsertRow(dict, spreadsheet_key, worksheet_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
      try:
         main()
      except:
         print "Insert Row Failed!"
```

This above gives the standard result. I've tried tinkering with re.findall(), but can't get either the right placement or right combination of conditions (r,'/d+', s and other things) to get it to return only the number 54.1... I basically end up with "Insert Row Failed"

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When you say, "the standard result," presumably you mean `Insert Row Failed!`, yes? I don't see anywhere in this particular snippet that you're doing anything to search for the `temp` key you describe; did you forget some of the code?

Comment: well, by standard result, I mean the "temp=54.1'C" that's noted in the first paragraph. when I start to try to insert re.findall() in various positions and configurations, I get the exception...

Comment: the command is "/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp" which you can just type in a terminal and it gives the temp=54.1'C. The way this script is set up, It's giving me that text string in a cell in my google doc. Then it continues to add a row and print the result every time it is run... which is what I want. I set it up in a crontab and I get data on a timer...

Comment: Ah, I see. So you're needing to add some processing to get the value (e.g. `54.1`, though it could presumably be a semi-arbitrary decimal) from the string returned by the command line function, correct?

Comment: yes, and I believe that the tempurature will have one decimal

Comment: See below; I've provided several options, ranging from quite broad to fairly specific.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track using `re`; your best bet (assuming the decimal can be arbitrary, etc.) is something like this:

```
import re

def temp():
    command = "/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp"
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    output = proc.stdout.read()

    # Build the regex. Use () to capture the group; we want any number of
    # digits \d or decimal points \. that is preceded by temp= and
    # followed by 'C
    temp_regex = re.compile(r'temp=([\d\.]*)\'C')
    matches = re.findall(temp_regex, output)   # now matches = ['54.1']

    temp = float(matches[0])
    return temp
```

The regex captures any combination of numbers and decimal places (e.g. `12.34.56` would get matched); you could restrict it if necessary to only allow a single decimal place, but that's more work than it appears to be worth, if you can trust that the data you're getting back is well-formed. If you do want the number to be more precise, you could compile the regex like this (for at least one numeral preceding the decimal place and exactly one following it):

```
temp_regex = re.compile(r'temp=(\d+.\d)\'C')
```

Again, we capture the expression using the parentheses (captured groups are [returned](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) by findall), but this time, increase the specificity of what we're looking for. This will capture any number like `123.4` but not `.4` and not `123.` If you find that you need to broaden it out a bit but still want only one decimal place:

```
temp_regex = re.compile(r'temp=(\d+.\d+)\'C')
```

That will capture any number with at least one numeral proceeding and following the decimal, so `1234.5678` would match but `1234.` would not and `.1234` would not.

As an alternative to using `re.findall()`, you might use `re.match()`, which returns [match objects](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects). Then your usage would look something like this (using the direct method, rather than pre-compiling the string:

```
match = re.match(r'temp=(\d+.\d+)\'C', output)
if match:
    temp = float(match.group(1))   # get the first matching group captured by ()
else:
    pass   # You should add some error handling here
```

One of the things this makes clearer than the way I had `re.findall()` above is that if nothing is captured, you have an issue, and you need to figure out how to handle it.

---

You can look at other ways to vary that up at [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), easily the best site I've found on the web for a quick resource on the topic.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post the examples. Unfortunately, I can't seem to implement them. I've tried all three forms, tried trimming it down removing the float. I'll keep trying, I guess I'll do some reading about 're.compile()', most examples I've seen here just use 're.findall()' directly... maybe I have too many instances of 'temp' in the code that's messing it up?

Comment: Ok, running the re.findall in IDLE, it keeps giving me a syntax error because of the 'C', I have to figure out how to get it to disregard that first tickmark (')

Comment: If you have `temp` repeatedly, that may indeed mess it up, which is why I included the `'C`. Note that the pattern actually escapes the quotation mark: `\'`. I tested this one exactly against your pattern, and it worked fine.

You don't *have* to use `re.compile()`; I did it because it makes it easier to see what step you're on. Also, you can use `re.match()` instead of `re.findall()`, which may actually make for nicer behavior; I'll add a note on how to do that to the question.

Comment: If you can give me a longer version of the string it returns, I can make sure the regex is working against it properly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out (at work) when I can, I'll have to ssh in to my Pi and try it out... longer version of the string it returns? Are we talking the "temp=54.1'C"? The only extra thing that's returned is some spaces or a line break, which I've been removing with 'output = output.replace("\n","")' I'm still wondering if I should be using double quotes instead of single. I seem to have both throughout the script. Should it be uniform?

Comment: Ah, to clarify, what I'm really asking is what is in `output` after the `proc.stdout.read()` call. If I have that whole string to test against, I can see where things might be breaking down. On quotes: being consistent is the biggest thing. I generally use single quotes for these sorts of things and then simply escape interior single quotes as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've already spent too much time messing with this. I couldn't seem to get the `output = proc.stdout.read()` to give me anything. I tried dozens of combinations of `re` with no luck.

Then I started looking at the replace() method. And it might not be the slickest way to go, but I know the output will always be in the form  of "temp=XX.X'C" (with X being numbers), so I just ended up doing this:

```
def temp():
   command = "/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp"
   proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
   output = proc.stdout.read()
   output1 = output.replace("temp=","")
   output2 = output1.replace("'C","")
   return output2
```

and it worked! It shows up in the Google Spreadsheet as a number just as I needed.

Thanks for the help on this anyway, I'll keep trying to implement `re` in other applications and maybe I'll find out why I couldn't get it to work with this.